# UIWebview doesn't execute javascript function

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I have a website which plays a video and when user pauses the video, my website redirect to another website. The js code is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myPlayer = document.getElementById("example_video_1");
    myPlayer.addEventListener('pause',function(){
        window.location.assign("http://www.baidu.com");
    },false);
</script>
```

But when I load this website in UIWebview, the website doesn't redirect to "http://www.baidu.com" after a user pauses the video. Why is this happening? Thanks.

Comment: does myPlayer.addEventListener get triggered on the video pause ??

Comment: In the browser, yes, but not triggered in UIWebview, I don't know why